# ¿Como hago para que la matriz de botones quede centrada?

Tags: java, matrices, botón

Buenas, estoy creando un programa y necesito que la matriz quede centrada.
¿De que forma puedo lograrlo?

Este es mi codigo para hacer la matriz de botones:

```
  private JPanel getPanel(){
    JButton bMatriz[][] = new JButton[5][5];
    JPanel panel= new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));

    for(int f=0;f<5;f++){
      for(int c=0;c<5;c++){
        bMatriz[f][c] = new JButton(""+f+","+c);
        bMatriz[f][c].setBounds(20,10,360,360);

        panel.setBounds(140,15,270,300);
        panel.add(bMatriz[f][c]); 

      }
    }
    return panel;
  }
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por casualidad querrás hacer algo como ésto?, sin embargo te cuento que lo modifiqué un toque para que sea visible, primero indefectiblemente lo tuve que extender de JFrame sino no te podía mostrar el ejemplo, segundo en vez de un método JPanel, lo cambié por un constructor y por último vas a ver la palabra this. la cual hace referencia a la clase actual, en este caso extiende de JFrame o el marco donde va a apoyado el JPanel.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JFrame{

    public Panel(){
        JButton bMatriz[][] = new JButton[5][5];

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
        this.add(panel);

        for (int f = 0; f < 5; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                bMatriz[f][c] = new JButton("" + f + "," + c);
                bMatriz[f][c].setBounds(20, 10, 360, 360);

                this.setBounds(140, 15, 270, 300);
                panel.setBounds(140, 15, 270, 300);
                panel.add(bMatriz[f][c]);
                panel.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

EL ejemplo que te pasé era si lo querías aplicar sólo desde una sola clase Java, sin embargo puede hacerse desde dos clases, donde en una definas los JPanel medidas etc, y en la otra sí o si extendiendolá de JFrame podés agregarle el JPanel o los JPanel que quieras. Ahora te muestro un ejemplo en dos Clases la primera contiene el JPanel y la segunda extiende de JFrame que es el marco o ventana donde va a estar apoyado el JPanel. (Igualmente yo prefiero todo en una clase sola)

**Definiendo el sólo el Panel en una clase**

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel{

    public JPanel getPanel(){
        JButton bMatriz[][] = new JButton[5][5];

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));


        for (int f = 0; f < 5; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                bMatriz[f][c] = new JButton("" + f + "," + c);
                bMatriz[f][c].setBounds(20, 10, 360, 360);

                panel.setBounds(140, 15, 270, 300);
                panel.add(bMatriz[f][c]);
                panel.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        return panel;
    }

}
```

**Definiendo el JFrame que va a agregar el o los JPanels**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameMaster extends JFrame {

    public JFrameMaster() {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        this.add(p.getPanel());
        this.setBounds(140, 15, 270, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*Acá no es necesario hacer nada más que crearlo, ya que el set Visible está incluido en el constructor*/
        JFrameMaster jfm = new JFrameMaster();
    }
}
```

**Acá va una imagen de cómo queda listo para salir andando**

[image: Acá la matriz de botones está centrada, se puede hacer de las dos formas, con una o dos clases o de muchas otras formas también.]

Comment: @roberto-rojas fijate si te sirve la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias @berlot83. Me ha servido mucho tu aporte.

Comment: @roberto-rojas Bueno fijate de ponerle algún voto a favor si podes

Comment: Listo :D  @berlot83

Comment: Si me pudieras ayudar otra vez :D.

Comment: es que necesito recibir de un JComboBox un valor int, para que ese valor sea el tamaño de la matriz de botones. Como puedo hacer para recibir el valor del JcomboBox como un tipo int??

Comment: Hola  @roberto-rojas , sí claro que te puedo ayudar, sin embargo esta pregunta ya está solucionada, o por lo menos por lo que la formulaste que eran los botones centrados, te pido que formules una nueva pregunta con los datos que ya tenés, y vemos cómo lo hacemos , y si podés cerrá ésta pregunta poniendo una tilde verde en mi respuesta si es que solucionó tu problema inicial. Formulá ñla pregunta claramente y pasame el link en un comentario de acá quizás yo u otra persona más experimentada te va a ayudar.